# Problems combining two JavaScript functions

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using autocomplete and add input box jquery functions in my form.

They are working good while use separately.

This is autocomplete function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $("#tamamla").autocomplete("tamamla.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});

</script>
```

This is add input box query

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {

        var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        var fMiktar = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"miktar\" name=\"miktar[]\" size=\"6px\" />");          
        var fOlcu = $("<select name=\"olcu[]\" onChange='showSelected(this.value)' class=\"olcu\" id=\"olcu\">Olcu</option> /"+'<?php while($olculer=mysql_fetch_array($hangiolcu2)){ echo "<option value=\"$olculer[olcu]\">$olculer[olcu]</option>";} ?>'+"</select>");
        var fMalzeme = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"malzeme[]\" class=\"malzeme\" id=\"tamamla\" />");
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(fMiktar);
        fieldWrapper.append(fOlcu);
        fieldWrapper.append(fMalzeme);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
    });

});
</script>
```

How can I use these scripts together.

```
  var fMalzeme = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"malzeme[]\" class=\"malzeme\" id=\"tamamla\" />");
```

Autocomplete is tow working when add new input box field using  #add function.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use an ID to refer to more than one element. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: don't use ids... simple as that

Comment: Understand but, how can autocomplete will be active when add new input box using by $("#add").click(function()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that in your first function, you're calling the `.autocomplete()` function on an element with a specified ID, but you're then creating more elements with that same ID. IDs need to be unique, so you can't have more than one element using the ID `tamamla`. Once you remove the duplicate IDs from your new HTML that you're creating, you can just do something like this inside your `add` function before appending everything to the `#buildyourform` element:

```
$("#add").click(function() {

    var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length + 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
    var fMiktar = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"miktar\" name=\"miktar[]\" size=\"6px\" />");          
    var fOlcu = $("<select name=\"olcu[]\" onChange='showSelected(this.value)' class=\"olcu\" id=\"olcu\">Olcu</option> /"+'<?php while($olculer=mysql_fetch_array($hangiolcu2)){ echo "<option value=\"$olculer[olcu]\">$olculer[olcu]</option>";} ?>'+"</select>");
    var fMalzeme = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"malzeme[]\" class=\"malzeme\" />");
    var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
    removeButton.click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    fieldWrapper.append(fMiktar);
    fieldWrapper.append(fOlcu);
    fMalzeme.autocomplete("tamamla.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
    fieldWrapper.append(fMalzeme);
    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
});
```

Since `fMalzeme` is an element created with the jQuery selector, you can call the `.autocomplete()` function on it just like any other selected element.